# Accessibility: How could I kill menu transparency improving legibility

Tags: big-sur

[image: Hard to read]

How could I get rid of transparency on big sur?

Comment: idk Big Sur, but you should be able to search system prefs for 'transparency' to find it.

Comment: Indeed. Feel free to write an answer to be upvoted.

Comment: No - you found it, you go for it. I don't need the points. Remember also to mark as accepted [there's probably a wait period before you can do that].

Answer (score 1):

per Tetsujin answer is comments
[image: Tetsujin answer]